# Ubuntu 14.04 - wget is hanging

Tags: maven, ubuntu, docker, wget, apt

I am trying to run install maven in my Docker image using this command:

```
RUN wget --no-proxy --no-verbose -O /tmp/apache-maven-3.2.2.tar.gz http://archive.apache.org/dist/maven/maven-3/3.2.2/binaries/apache-maven-3.2.2-bin.tar.gz
```

But it just hangs in the command line terminal. No output, nothing after that. I don't even get prompted to enter another command in the shell until I hit ctrl + C.

**EDIT 1**: I tried running the command with `--no-proxy` and this was the result once again:

```
root@2ff7e62d1e7c:/# wget --no-verbose -O /tmp/apache-maven-3.2.2.tar.gz http://
archive.apache.org/dist/maven/maven-3/3.2.2/binaries/apache-maven-3.2.2-bin.tar.
gz
2015-08-16 17:19:07 URL:http://archive.apache.org/dist/maven/maven-3/3.2.2/binar
ies/apache-maven-3.2.2-bin.tar.gz [6940967/6940967] -> "/tmp/apache-maven-3.2.2.
tar.gz" [1]
```

I also get the above output, even after running `wget` **without** `--no-proxy`

**EDIT 2:** Ok it did download the file (I think), but it's in a red color?

```
apache-maven-3.2.2.tar.gz
```

IS in /tmp/apache-maven-3.2.2.tar.gz on the container, but its in a red color?

**EDIT 3:** Ok the `wget` worked I just had to run it a few times. I'll leave this question up in case others may find it useful.

Comment: Some things you can do to debug your networking connection: (1) try pinging the address first before trying to wget from it (2) try pinging 8.8.8.8 to determine if you are on the internet at all

Comment: @Chris Beck internet connectivity and accessing the URL is good

Comment: i just tried it and i got this: http://hastebin.com/sukurohava.avrasm so i guess it's an issue with docker?

Comment: I've run into this when I've had a proxy environment variable defined ... and then forgot about it.  Try running wget with `--no-proxy`.

Comment: @Chris Beck, interesting, this was my output this time when I ran the same command: `root@2ff7e62d1e7c:/# wget --no-verbose -O /tmp/apache-maven-3.2.2.tar.gz http://
archive.apache.org/dist/maven/maven-3/3.2.2/binaries/apache-maven-3.2.2-bin.tar.
gz
2015-08-16 17:19:07 URL:http://archive.apache.org/dist/maven/maven-3/3.2.2/binar
ies/apache-maven-3.2.2-bin.tar.gz [6940967/6940967] -> "/tmp/apache-maven-3.2.2.
tar.gz" [1]`

Comment: I'll try running with --no-proxy